# How to escape string in `jq`?

Tags: jq

I'd like to just print `a`. I don't find how to do so. Could anybody let me know how to do it? Thanks.

```
$ jq '.' <<< '"a"'
"a"
```

Comment: use raw flag? `jq -r '.' <<< '"a"'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--raw-output`/`-r` flag.

From the documentation:

> With this option, if the filter’s result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.